# MQ client series protocol - using LR 9.0

Tags: loadrunner

1) Does LoadRunner have a protocol for MQ?

2) Is it possible to use a LoadRunner Vuser to drive load (put messages) into an MQ queue?

3) Would we need to purchase something from HP or some other vendor to do this? If so, from which vendor and what is the estimate price?

Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes:  MQ Tester.  It does require an extra licensed component.  Ships on disc two of the installation media.
2. Yes.  You may use MQ Tester (as shipped), Winsock, JMS (via Java Virtual user) or JMS (via Web Services Virtual User.  There is a strong possibility that you could leverage the VB MQ API with the VB virtual user although I have never tested this combination directly.  You also have the option of a custom DLL using the MQ API as a client type (see Virtual User guide, advanced concepts, developing scripts in Visual Studio)
3. Yes, if you don't already have a licensed protocol which can do the trick (see 1 and 2 above)

You have many options to place a message on MQ.   At one of my current clients we use a combination of a Java Virtual User with custom code leveraging JMS to place a message on the queue.   Long term this client will be moving to either Winsock or Web Services (we have licenses for both) dependent upon the results of our testing with both to see which one is a better fit on both the technology and the client skills front - Winsock has a higher technical barrier to cross but it is lighter in overall virtual user resource weight.